# Remove datagrid rows based on a cell value

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, row

I have a datagrid called `dataGridView1`, it has a cell contains a date, I want to color some rows based in the following code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
     if ((Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[7].Value) - DateTime.Today).Days <= 90)
     {
         row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
     }
}
```

This code succeeds on that. What I want is to remove all remaining rows which are not colored, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=dgv.Rows.count-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    if ((Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[7].Value) - DateTime.Today).Days <= 90)
     {
         row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
     }
     else
     {
         dgv.rows.removeAt(i);
     }
}
```